# How to fix asphalt cracked in large chunks?

Tags: repair, driveway, asphalt

I have a small asphalt ramp from the garage sloping towards the alley.

It seems that either the salt or the city snow plowers cracked the corner and shattered a section of it.

I tried to piece it back together.  How can I fill in the cracks and keep it together?

[Here's what it looks like](https://m.imgur.com/9faXBMf)

[image]

Comment: I agree with RedGrittyBrick.  When asphalt breaks up as in the picture, it usually means that the ground under the asphalt has settled, and those pieces aren't well-supported.  Just filling the cracks doesn't solve the underlying problem and the repair will just break up again.  The solution is to remove the pieces, compact the base, and then fill it with fresh asphalt or asphalt patch, following the directions.

Answer (score 2):

> **How can I fill in the cracks and keep it together?**

I wouldn't do that.

I would search for a local supplier of [asphalt patch](https://www.google.com/search?q=asphalt+patch)

Random example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You  have to cut out the bad area, compact the base and fill in with a some patch. Lowes has one that works pretty well. You can rent a concrete saw to cut it, try a diamond blade in a circular saw, or go after it with a pickaxe. I recommend getting a hand compactor to use on the dirt under the whole and then on the patch itself. They are a flat plate with a handle to tamp it with. Lowes and Home Depot have them. Use a hard yard rake flipped over helps as a leveler.